# Proposal: [parental-controls] tag wiki excerpt should be edited, so that it's not Windows-specific

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

## Situation

The [tag wiki excerpt](https://superuser.com/tags/parental-controls/info) of the [parental-controls](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/parental-controls) tag makes it clear that the tag is Windows-specific.

## Problem

But Mac- and Linux-using parents, too, might want to impose parental controls upon their kids.

## Solution

I propose that the excerpt should be replaced with the following:

"Parental-control tools are usually used by parents to help control their kids' use of technology. Time limits, monitoring, Web filtering, social-networking monitoring, preventing the use of mature games such as Grand Theft Auto, and so on."

## Bonus idea

If it's OK with you, the full tag wiki could also say: "Parental-control tools can also be used by adults, to serve as self-control tools."

## Side notes

(Yes, I know [web-filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-filtering) exists. But the two tags are different. Not all web filtering is imposed upon kids ([some](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81334/pluckeye-is-an-internet-filter-with-a-time-delay-feature-on-a-multi-user-window) is self-imposed). And not all parental controls are about web filtering. Some parental controls are about time controls, or Facebook-friend monitoring, or other such things. So the two tags should be kept separate. You could add a "see also" if you wanted.)

Comment: I'm a linux using parent dang it, I want to be included too!

Comment: That was a joke, but thanks!. Upvoted as I agree anyway.

Comment: Ah OK :) Still, there definitely are options on Linux. For example, there's e2guardian, which is the successor to DansGuardian. You can run it on each machine, or maybe even on one central gateway. You could look at its logs from time to time. There may be other tools too.

Comment: This feels like it should be a retag request  as well as a broadening of the current tag.  The current tag appears to be specifically for the [Windows Parental Controls](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10524/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-7/) feature but it could well be made more general to suit other operating systems.  I'd be tempted to add [tag:windows-parental-controls] and retag whichever questions are specifically asking about that feature.

Comment: @Mokubai: If you want that, for clarity, maybe you should: A) Call it [microsoft-parental-controls](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-parental-controls). B) Then write a clear tag wiki excerpt. C) Then hope that people won't use it to tag questions about non-Microsoft parental-control utilities, such as Qustodio for Windows.

Comment: Actual usage looks like a majority are about the Microsoft tool that has changed names a few times.  The rest are either about other tools of the same function or the general concept of usage control.  I would suggest two tags, one for the Microsoft tool, the other for everything else.  The wiki excerpts should include guidance to use only the applicable tag, not both.  If another application has enough questions specific to it to warrant a separate tag, we could always break out additional ones.

Comment: re:bonus idea--in practice, whoever sets it up can easily change it, so parental controls aren't typically an effective solution.  For that matter, a lot of parents have to ask their kids to set up their own controls.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234: If you have a friend hold the password, or you use FutureMe or WhenSend or Pluckeye, or if you [lock the passphrase on a piece of paper in your car trunk](https://www.reddit.com/r/pornfree/comments/5xty9m/idea_for_programmers_you_could_write_a_timedelay/), you can use parental controls to protect yourself.